# Must the endomorphism ring of a finitely generated module be Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian

Let $A$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative). If it helps, one can assume that $A$ is right hereditary (i.e. every submodule of a projective right $A$-module is projective). Let $M$ be a finitely generated module and $B=\text{End}(M)$. Is it true that $B$ is Noetherian?

I think this is true for commutative $A$. Then $B$ would be a Noetherian $A$-module, and since any ideal in $B$ could be considered an $A$-module, the fact that $B$ is a Noetherian $A$-module would imply that $B$ is a Noetherian $B$-module. That is, a Noetherian ring.

But is this true in the non-commutative case?

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is a Noetherian (or right Noetherian) ring? Otherwise *every* ring $B$ is the endomorphism ring of a finitely generated module, since it's the endomorphism ring of the rank one free module $B\!_B$ over itself.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard No, I don't have any Noetherian hypotheses on $A$. But you are right, $B_B$ gives a perfect counterexample.